# CakePHP 2 IE Conditional CSS in default.ctp

Tags: php, css, internet-explorer, cakephp

I am developing an application using CakePHP 2 and have come up against an issue in the default.ctp template file. I have had a hunt around the web and am unable to find an answer that works for me. I can't find a way to have a conditional CSS file included for IE.

I am doing the following for my normal CSS

```
echo $this->Html->css(array('screen', 'print'));

echo $this->fetch('css');
```

And this works fine and produces the following html.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/screen.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/print.css" />
```

What I need to be able to add to the above CSS is the following conditional include

```
<!--[if IE]> <link rel="stylesheet" type="/text/css" href="/css/ie.css" /> <![endif]-->
```

I can not see how to include the ie.css into the array of css files before the fetch.

I would appreciate any help in solving this issue.

Regards

rickl

Answer (score 2):

Just add css between IE conditional block i.e

```
<!--[if IE]>
<?php $this->Html->css(array('ie'); ?>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Conditional CSS Includes**:

Add the following to your **Layout**:

```
<?php if ($ieCond = $this->fetch('ie')): ?>
<!--[if IE]><?php echo $ieCond; ?><![endif]-->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Add the following to your **View**:

```
<?php $this->Html->css('ie', array('block' => 'ie')); ?>
```

Source: [CakePHP Api](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-HtmlHelper.html#_css)

Tested in IE11 and FF → Works for me.